# Is there a way to bundle my python app with all its dependencies so I can distribute it to an average user?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, tkinter, centos, dependency-management

I built a python app using tkinter and now I would like to make it available to my user base.
The problem I'm facing is that the whereas the app can simply be launched by launching the 'main.py' file, it requires users to install like two dozen dependencies and libraries to run correctly.
(numpy, cython, tkinter, etc)
I do not want to make users do all this because that becomes a non-starter for the average user.
I just want users to launch my app with a double click or in Linux(a simple executable file)

Can you link me to a guide where I can learn how to do this? I'm still in university and this is my first time building a GUI so I do not know where to start.

Comment: How one packages all the dependencies will depend on the OS. What OS are you using? If Linux, which distro?

Comment: ah, I have a lot to learn. I am using centOS linux

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you want users to be able to edit the code or just run the program. If you are just looking for a good way to package your program to distribute to others, Pyinstaller may be a good place to look.

Pyinstaller is a free program which bundles Python programs (and dependencies) into an executable format. You can find more information at https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I don't want users to be able to edit the code so I think this may work for me.